# Why is the JSON results "undefined" in this JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having some issues getting my JS to work right. I am trying to select an option from a dropdown which then calls this function. The function is being called properly (type is set to 'truck' and id is set to 5). I want to then use the data returned to populate several fields. The alert() I added to test gives me "undefined".

Here is my JS:

```
 function getDueDates(type, id) {
     $.getJSON("loadVehicle.php",
     {
         id: id,
         type: type
     },
         function(data) {            
            alert( "TEST: " + data.year);
             $("#inspection_due").val(data.inspection_due);
             $("#short_due").val(data.short_due);
             $("#full_due").val(data.full_due);
         }
 )};
```

When I check the loadVehicle page manually (with id=5, type=truck) I get:

```
[{"truck_id":"5","status":"A","truck_number":"21","year":"1999","make":"Freightliner","model":"Classic","engine":"Detroit","vin_number":"1FUPCSZB2XPA16977","transmission_number":"","tire_size":"","inspection_due":"2009-04-30","short_due":"0000-00-00","full_due":"0000-00-00","comments":"Caf Inc Truck","web_id":"b963940bfd96528f7fd57c08628221f0","last_update":"2009-03-09 16:26:28"}]
```

But in the page the alert comes up with "TEST: undefined"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `data[0].year` since you are getting an *array* containing a single object.

Comment: Damn your speed, karim79. (+1)

Comment: @Matt - Hehe, I owe it to "Mavis Beacon Teaches Typing" which taught me to touch type when I was a teenager, and having answered at least 10 questions like this :)

Comment: I knew there was something other than Number Munchers, Word Munchers and Oregon Trail. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

Try data[0].year.

It looks like your loadVehicle.php is returning an array of objects not just one object.